# Como retornar Id de uma stream?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stream

Preciso pegar o ID dentro do findById, mas não entendi como consigo fazer isso em stream.

```
 @Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    //TODO ler argumentos com data e workflow de processamento enviada pelo airflow
    try {
        List<String> arguments = Arrays.stream(args)
                .filter(key -> !key.contains("--spring.profiles.active"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        //yyyy-MM-dd;
        TaskEnum task = TaskEnum.valueOf(arguments.get(0));
        LocalDate processingDate = LocalDate.parse(arguments.get(1));
        UUID airflowId = UUID.fromString(arguments.get(2));

        amqpHelper.createTopology(airflowId, task);
        Collection<OmniMessageDataDTO> entities = Arrays.asList();
        List<OmniMessageDataDTO> data = entities.stream().forEach(omniMessageDataRepository.findById());

        switch (task) {
            case PROCESSING_FETCH_RUPTURES_LIST -> fetchRupturesListService.processList(omniMessageDataDTO, airflowId);
        }
```

Comment: Se for o findById do spring-data-jpa, ele retorna um Optional com a entidade, você pode utilizar o método get para recuperar a entidade e então obter o id desejado. Exemplo: findById(1).get().getId() ... Tomar o cuidado de verificar se o findById retornou alguma coisa.

Comment: @AndreyFrança o pessoal usa JDBC puro nos batches por questão de performance. Não sei se tem como fazer dessa forma por esse motivo. E também tem a questão de que o findbyid recebe um parametro... eu to viajando legal nisso.

Answer (score 0):

Use o método `.map()` para projetar a uma saída diferente e então use o `findAllById(List<Long> ids)` presente na herança `JpaRepository`;

```
List<Long> ids = entities.stream().map(OmniMessageDataDTO::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<OmniMessageDataDTO> data = omniMessageDataRepository.findAllById(ids);
```

> Porém o retorno do método `findAllById(List<Long> ids)` não é o tipo Dto,
> a não ser que seu modelo de entidade seja esse.

Creio que seja assim:

```
List<Long> ids = colecaoDto.stream().map(OmniMessageDataDTO::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<OmniMessageData> data = omniMessageDataRepository.findAllById(ids);
```